# Django ModelAdmin/ModelForm readonly permissions flow

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django admin application and I have a particular issue with one of the admin pages.

I have a model which looks like this.

```
class Quote(CommonModel, models.Model):

    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Approved credit amount")
```

The form looks like this:

```
class QuoteForm(django.forms.ModelForm):

    amount = django.forms.CharField(widget=django.forms.TextInput())
```

and the ModelAdmin looks like this:

```
class QuoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = QuoteForm
```

Now I need to amend this amount to format it so that it reads in dollars and cents from the int value in the database, this is not an issue in the form when the user has change permissions to the ModelAdmin, I have ammended the form to look like this:

```
class QuoteForm(django.forms.ModelForm):

amount = django.forms.CharField(widget=django.forms.TextInput())


def clean_approved_amount_amount(self, value: str):
    return self.convert_string_float_dollar_representation_to_cent_integer(
        self.cleaned_data['approved_amount_amount']
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['amount'] = kwargs['instance'].integer_values_in_dollar_format(kwargs['instance']['amount'])
```

But if the user only has read only permissions to the ModelAdmin the form flow is different and fails and I can't seem to figure out when the ModelAdmin picks up that the form is readonly so that I can convert the value in the DB to a dollar and cent amount.

There is no documentation on this conditional flow that I can find to understand when I should hook into the process to amend the readonly version of this field.